# Encode A11B modulo 37

Tags: self-learning, coding-theory

Encode the word A11B modulo 37 using the encoding
0=0, 1=1, . . . , 9=9, A=10, B=11, . . . , Z=35, blank space=36.

I took the weighted sum: 5(10) + 4(1) + 3(1) + 2(11) + 1(c) ≡ 0 mod 37
Solving, i got c ≡ 32 mod 37, which is V. hence getting A11BV

However the solution given is A11BI, which is the correct answer? And why?

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is base of $A11B$? If it is in base $37$ the result is obviously $B.$

Comment: I think the base is 37. Why is it obviously B?

Comment: Because in base $37$ your number is $B + 1\times 37 + 1 \times 37^2 + A \times 37^3$ and the remainder modulo $37$ is $B$, like the remainder modulo $10$ in base $10$ is the last decimal digit.